# Java Code To Create Auto Running PacMan in Pacman Game

Tags: java, auto, pacman

I am attempting to modify the pacman game from the Mason 19 website.  What I have to do is make pacman run on its own and traverse any board given as fast as possible.  So far I have achieved making pacman running on its own but it gets stuck in a loop at the top of the board.  What I want to know is what would be the best way to make it work and not get stuck in a loop.

The program I am using code from comes from Mason19 https://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/

The code I have modified is inside the Pac.java and the doPolicyStep class.

```
    protected void doPolicyStep(SimState state)
    {
        if(lastAction == NOTHING)
        {
            if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.E))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.E;
                performAction(Pac.E);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.S))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.S;
                performAction(Pac.S);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.N))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.N;
                performAction(Pac.N);
            }
            else
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.W;
                performAction(Pac.W);

            }
        }

        else if(lastAction == Pac.E)
        {
            if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.E)) 
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.E;
                performAction(Pac.E);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.S))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.S;
                performAction(Pac.S);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.N))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.N;
                performAction(Pac.N);
            }
            else
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.W;
                performAction(Pac.W);
            }
        }
        else if(lastAction == Pac.S)
        {
            if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.S)) 
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.S;
                performAction(Pac.S);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.W))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.W;
                performAction(Pac.W);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.E))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.E;
                performAction(Pac.E);
            }
            else
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.N;
                performAction(Pac.N);
            }
        }
        else if(lastAction == Pac.W)
        {
            if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.W)) 
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.W;
                performAction(Pac.W);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.N))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.N;
                performAction(Pac.N);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.S))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.S;
                performAction(Pac.S);
            }
            else
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.E;
                performAction(Pac.E);
            }
        }
        else if(lastAction == Pac.N)
        {
            if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.N)) 
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.N;
                performAction(Pac.N);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.W))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.W;
                performAction(Pac.W);
            }
            else if(isPossibleToDoAction(Pac.E))
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.E;
                performAction(Pac.E);
            }
            else
            {
                pacman.actions[0] = Pac.S;
                performAction(Pac.S);
            }
        }
    int nextAction = pacman.getNextAction(tag);
```

/** The Method isPossibleToDoAction() Determines if the agent can move with the given action (N/W/S/E/NOTHING) without bumping into a wall.  */

```
public boolean isPossibleToDoAction(int action)
    {
    if (action == NOTHING)
        {
        return false;  // no way
        }
    IntGrid2D maze = pacman.maze;
    int[][] field = maze.field;

    // the Agents grid is discretized exactly on 1x1 boundaries so we can use floor rather than divide

    // the agent can straddle two locations at a time.  The basic location is x0, y0, and the straddled location is x1, y1.
    // It may be that x0 == y0.
    int x0 = (int) location.x;
    int y0 = (int) location.y;
    int x1 = location.x == x0 ? x0 : x0 + 1;
    int y1 = location.y == y0 ? y0 : y0 + 1;

    // for some actions we can only do the action if we're not straddling, or if our previous action was NOTHING
    if ((x0 == x1 && y0 == y1) || lastAction == NOTHING)
        {
        switch (action)
            {
            // we allow toroidal actions
            case N:
                return (field[maze.stx(x0)][maze.sty(y0 - 1)] == 0);
            case E:
                return (field[maze.stx(x0 + 1)][maze.sty(y0)] == 0);
            case S:
                return (field[maze.stx(x0)][maze.sty(y0 + 1)] == 0);
            case W:
                return (field[maze.stx(x0 - 1)][maze.sty(y0)] == 0);
            }
        } // for other actions we're continuing to do what we did last time.
    // assuming we're straddling, this should always be allowed unless our way is blocked
    else if (action == lastAction)
        {
        switch (action)
            {
            // we allow toroidal actions
            case N:  // use y0
                return (field[maze.stx(x0)][maze.sty(y0)] == 0);
            case E:  // use x1
                return (field[maze.stx(x1)][maze.sty(y0)] == 0);
            case S:  // use y1
                return (field[maze.stx(x0)][maze.sty(y1)] == 0);
            case W:  // use x0
                return (field[maze.stx(x0)][maze.sty(y0)] == 0);
            }
        } // last there are reversal actions.  Generally these are always allowed as well.
    else if ((action == N && lastAction == S) ||
        (action == S && lastAction == N) ||
        (action == E && lastAction == W) ||
        (action == W && lastAction == E))
        {
        return true;
        }

    return false;
    }
```

I believe I need to use something like a BFS search to find the shortest path, I just have no idea how to do that.

Comment: "it gets stuck in a loop", I see no loop in your code and also what does `isPossibleToDoAction` do?

Comment: There is no loop in the code but pacman loops at the top left corner of the board when it runs.  isPossibleToDoAction checks to see if if while pacman is running it can go N,S,E, or W on the board when it encounters a wall.

Comment: I meant could you post the code for that method.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I edited the original post and included that method.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I feel like I need a stack or something like that to keep track of each move made.

Comment: That added code unfortunately didn't clarify anything since it's just to much code and instance variables etc. I think your best way forward here is to use the debugger to track down the issue(s) with your code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I know my code is wrong (the first code included).  What I think I need to do is use a BFS to get the fastest way through the board and then somehow translate that to moves on the actual game.  Would you happen to know of any way to do that?